# How to unlock Xcode controls

Tags: xcode

I don't know how my controls in this xib some became light grey and can't move the index level. Is anyone have idea? thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because those disabled controls are not installed for the selected size class you are working on.
Documentation for Size classes and Storyboard is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH10-SW1) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436)
Hope this helps.